# Using shortcuts to create identical file structure

Tags: unix, debian, symbolic-link

I've got a Debian based OS with TV shows spread over multiple disks but the series are not all on the same disk.  For example, Show1 has 10 Season, Season 1,2, 4 and 5 are on Disk1, 3, 6 and 8 on Disk2 and 7, 9 and 10 on Disk3.  What I'd like to do is have create shortcuts so regardless of whether I'm browsing Disk1, Disk2 or Disk3 I see all TV shows and all the seasons subdirectories whether they're on that disk or not.

Is there is a command, script or a utility to create shortcuts in this or some other method to achieve these results?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If your disks are all mounted in the same directory, it shouldn't be too hard to do with a simple loop. E.g.: `/media/Disk1`, `/media/Disk2`, `/media/Disk3`:

```
cd /media
for season in */*; do
    for disk in Disk1 Disk2 Disk3; do
        ln -s "$(readlink -f "${season}")" "${disk}"
    done
done
```

There will be some collisions (i.e. files attempting to symlink to themselves), but they'll just throw harmless errors, and won't stop the links from being created.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into using loops a bit more and try to get something that suits for my needs to create shortcuts for all the shows as well as all the seasons.